# Using laravel {{ }} in @foreach

Tags: laravel

Could someone explain to me why this syntax doesn't work?

```
@foreach({{ ($arrayOfProducts->count()/3 == 0) ? '$arrayOfProducts as $item' : '$arrayOfProducts->chunk(($arrayOfProducts->count()/3)) as $chunk' }})

@endforeach
```

[A picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqV1F.png)

Comment: Please post a source code itself, not a picture, as it might help other users to refer to it when they read your post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn basic syntax.

```
@foreach($arrayOfProducts as $product)
  {{ $product->someAttr }}
@endforeach
```

This would work just fine, behind the scenes it's just basic PHP `foreach` loop, and `{{ }}` is just `echo`, also try to keep that conditional logic in your controller for more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#loops) you need to use the `@foreach` / `@endforeach` in a similar way as the standard php `foreach` loop.

In your code you are actually passing strings as arguments of your loop. if you want to make it work you need to pass your condition on `$arrayOfProducts`and then loop over it.

```
@foreach(($arrayOfProducts->count()/3 == 0) ? $arrayOfProducts : $arrayOfProducts->chunk(($arrayOfProducts->count()/3))) as $item)

{{ dump($item) }}

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not :

```
@if($arrayOfProducts->count()/3 == 0)
   @foreach($arrayOfProducts as $item)
     {{$item}}
   @endforeach
@else
   @foreach($arrayOfProducts->chunk(($arrayOfProducts->count()/3)) as $chunk)
     {{$chunk}}
   @endforeach
@endif
```

Don't try to use ternary operator in that way, it's cleaner like this and it's readable for you for the future, at least everytime you'll see the code you'll instantly know what it does

**EDIT:** ->count() is there like this only because arrayOfProducts is actually a collection?

Comment: Yes, it's a collection.
I'm using ternary operator because, my code is already pretty long, I use that @foreach to print <figure></figure> with other divs inside

Comment: Well, if you have a pretty big blade just use partials, men
Anyway, @Christophe Hubert has gived you the answer if you want to proceed with a ternary operator.
 But If you want to listen to an advice, use partials and use mine solution. It's cleaner in any case and more maintainable

Comment: Also if it's a colletion don't name it arrayOfProducts, naming is important